# Web frontend for REST service api in spring-boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where I have created a RESTful api, using @RestController, that allows me to maintain a list of devices (add/delete/update) in a mysql backend.

I am now trying to create a web frontend that allows me to make use of this API and found Spring MVC + Thymeleaf suitable for this, as it enables me to  dynamically populate the view with device details.

Is there anyway I can call into the REST API from the MVC controller code? So for e.g.

1. /upload/devices is a MVC endpoint that would present me with a form where I can upload a list of devices
2. When I hit "submit" on the form, the MVC controller backend will POST into /api/upload/devices REST API and return view with parameters set for pass/fail on upload

Is it possible to do this or am I doing something that is bad design.

The reason I have a pure REST API using @restcontroller is so that I can call them from other applications that need json responses (json list of devices for e.g.) instead of a view.

I can also think of implementing a pure angular based front-end that calls into the REST API, but that would mean I can't use thymeleaf which I like for templating and injecting service side variables.

cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply create another `@Controller` class to emulate that `@RestController` one. If the Service layer is designed properly it will be a simple call to get the data. The major difference is the view portion. That will be where you do your work. With Rest it's easy just output the object and the implicit @ResponseBody takes care of the serialization. With the Controller style you will be passing back the view as you know. That's the major difference.

Doing a call from the Controller to a REST backend that's being served from the same application is redundant.

Comment: Thanks! This strategy worked well for me. I pushed all my logic into service layers and utility classes, and both the REST and MVC controllers are now able to call into common code.